# Memory leaks with CoreImage

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, core-image

Instruments detect this code with memory leaks

```
- (UIImage *)blurryOriginalImageWithLevel:(CGFloat)blur
{
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ss"].CGImage];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"
                              keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, inputImage,
                    @"inputRadius", @(blur),
                    nil];

CIImage *outputImage =inputImage;
if (filter) {
    outputImage=filter.outputImage;
}

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef outImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[inputImage extent]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outImage];
CGImageRelease(outImage);
return image;
}
```

screenshots：
[image: enter image screenshots1]

[image: enter image screenshots2]

but I can't find any problem in this code,am I wrong?

Comment: Wait - you're worried because you might be leaking _one byte_?

Comment: No matter 1 byte or 1 mb,I think memory leak is not allow,for example,this code is invoked 1000 times,there will be 1000 byte leaks.@matt

Comment: But since it would be Apple's leak, not yours, what can you do about it? File a bug report with Apple if you think there's a problem.